Buddha puja (offering) defines as giving with respect, in here from which cetasikas the respect is made of?
When we offer something like food to a buddha statue (a buddha puja) the buddha statue has no benefit from it.. But we offer it (buddha puja) as a respect to buddha and gain merits.. so the buddha puja defines as giving with respect..
According to abhidhamma alobha cetasika, is the basic reason for giving ..like that I think saddha, is the basic reason for respect here.. if so what cetasika is the respect (or from what cetasikas the respect is made of?) in this occasion..

http://www.abhidhamma.com/Chart_Cetasika_en.pdf

The following quote from the Mahaparinibbana Sutta tells the building of a memorial monument (stupa), and the benefits of witnessing it and honouring it. It mainly serves as a source of inspiration and confidence.
Presumably, a Buddha statue would serve as a similar source of inspiration and confidence.

They build a monument for the wheel-turning monarch at the crossroads.
That’s how they proceed with a wheel-turning monarch’s corpse. Proceed
in the same way with the Realized One’s corpse. A monument for the
Realized One is to be built at the crossroads. When someone there
lifts up garlands or fragrance or powder, or bows, or inspires
confidence in their heart, that will be for their lasting welfare and
happiness.
And for what reason is a Realized One worthy of a monument? So that
many people will inspire confidence in their hearts, thinking: ‘This
is the monument for that Blessed One, perfected and fully awakened!’
And having done so, when their body breaks up, after death, they are
reborn in a good place, a heavenly realm. It is for this reason that a
Realized One is worthy of a monument.
Mahaparinibbana Sutta (DN 16)

